# How to put a JPanel with 2DGraphics on a JFrame (same class)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, graphics2d

I have a class that extends JFrame and I would like to add two JPanels to that JFrame: a text panel and a graphics panel. My text panel is a panel containing a label with text. My graphics panel will contain a graph (created using 2DGraphics). I'm adding the graphic panel to the left side (0,0) and the text panel to right side (1,0) using a gridbaglayout method. However, the graphic panel won't show up in the frame. I have tried numerous methods to try to get the panel to show up with no success.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicsTest extends JFrame {

    private final JPanel textPanel;
    private final JLabel textLabel;

    public GraphicsTest() {
        textPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        textLabel = new JLabel("Home label");

        this.setBounds(180, 112, 1080, 675);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        textPanel.add(textLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        addComponent(this, new GraphicPanel(), 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
        addComponent(this, textPanel, 1, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class GraphicPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            // drawing lots of shapes and lines, removed for readibility
        }   

    }

    public void addComponent(JFrame frame, JComponent component, int x, int y, int width, int height, int align) {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = x;
        c.gridy = y;
        c.gridwidth = width;
        c.gridheight = height;
        c.weightx = 100.0;
        c.weighty = 100.0;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 0);
        c.anchor = align;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        frame.add(component, c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsTest gui = new GraphicsTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: One problem -- your graphics panel's preferred size looks to be 0, 0, and since you're not expanding the fill or using a layout that will expand for you, such as a gridlayout, the size will likely be 0, 0.

Comment: Don't override paint(). Just place your custom painting code in the `paintComponent()` method. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples and more information and working examples, including how to override the `getPreferredSize()` method.

Comment: I've overridden the `getPreferredSize()` method (set dimensions to 700, 700), as well as transferred my custom painting code to a `paintComponent()` method (deleting the paint method I had initially). The panel still doesn't show up though, I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: "I've overridden the getPreferredSize()...." please update your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me when I use a size like (200, 200).

GridbagLayout works such that if a component can't be displayed at its preferred size, then it will be displayed at its minimum size, which would be (0, 0).

So whether (700, 700) works will depend on your screen resolution. It also works at (700, 600) for my screen.

I question if you want to use a GridBadLayout. Maybe just use a BorderLayout. The custom painting panel would go in the CENTER so it will grow/shrink as the frame size changes. The other panel would go to the LINE_END, so it will remain at a fixed size.